# What is an easy way to add new user

Tags: user-management

I have read about the command sudo adduser newuser and sudo passwd -l but if I understood correct I have to grant every thing by terminal. I created easily a new user by Systems>User Accounts but it is disable and I didn't find where entry the password and set the grants. Is there an easy way by windows instead of terminal? If not, what is the simplest way to create an user that will be equivalent to a Microsoft Windows 8 user but without administration privileges?

Comment: top-right corner - you need to click the unlock button before clicking the password field.  Are you sure you can add users without administrator rights in windows? doubtful - sounds like a security flaw to me.

Answer (score 1):

- You have to first **unlock** to change in user accounts as follows:

[image: screen1]

- Then add user as follows:

[image]

- And make new account as **Standard** if you would not to create as
  **Administrative**:

[image]

Comment: Pandya, thank you. And how did a enter a password and force the user to change when log in?